# Hibernate Search 5.5 Message Driven Bean for Master/Slave implementation

Tags: master-slave, nhibernate-search

Hibernate documentation doesn't mention what has to be done in the MDB

```
This example inherits from the abstract JMS controller class available in the Hibernate Search
source code and implements a JavaEE MDB. This implementation is given as an example and
can be adjusted to make use of non Java EE Message Driven Beans. Essentially what you need
to do is to connect the specific JMS Queue with the SearchFactory instance of the EntityManager.
As an advanced alternative, you can implement your own logic by not extending AbstractJMSHibernateSearchController
but rather to use it as an implementation example.
```

In 5.5 we cant find AbstractJMSHibernateSearchController class. Please help to know what has to be implemented.

Basically i was implementing Master/Slave using Hibernate Search with 4.2

I am getting below exception, trying to upgrade to latest version

```
org.hibernate.search.store.impl.FSSlaveDirectoryProvider - HSEARCH000021: Unable to synchronize source of C:\hisindex-slave\com.abc.his.warehouse.model.base.Client
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\hisindex-slave\com.abc.his.house.model.base.Client\2\_3.fdt (The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
```